# How to prevent NPE when accessing a nested/indexed property of a bean

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils, nested-properties

Is there any way to prevent NPE when accessing a nested bean using commons-beanutils?
Here is my code:

```
new BeanUtilsBean().getProperty(human, "parent.name");
```

In this case I want `getProperty()` to either return empty string ("") when `human.getParent() == null` or handle it in a way other that throwing an NPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They were thinking of [adding](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000047.html) language features to JDK7, but [ultimately they weren't added](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/editor/archive/2009/09/01/project-coin-final-update-list-jdk-7)

For now you'll have to manually check.  You can just hack it and create a function like

```
public static void propertyHack(Object bean, String property, String nullreplace){
  try{
    return new BeanUtilsBean().getProperty(bean, property);
  }
  catch(NullPointerException npe){
    return nullreplace;
  }
}
```

Kind of sucks, but it will work.

Comment: Well NPE may be thrown for other causes, say bean itself is null. Isn't there any feature in beanutils to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

`PropertyUtils` has a specific method for nested properties `getNestedProperty(...)` that handles NPE by throwing a `NestedNullException`, which is probably(?) better for the eye.

Here is the [Javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#getNestedProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

If someone else is searching the answer

```
    Guia g = new Guia();
    GuiaParticipante gp = new GuiaParticipante(1);
    g.setTbGuiaParticipanteCollection(Collections.singletonList(gp));//comment this line to test
    String name = "tbGuiaParticipanteCollection[0].codParticipante";//the expression itself
    Resolver resolver = new DefaultResolver();//used to "clean" the expression
    if (resolver.isIndexed(name)) {
        String property = resolver.getProperty(name);//remove the [0].codParticipante

        if (PropertyUtils.getProperty(g, property) != null) { //get the collection object, so you can test if is null
            String cod = BeanUtils.getNestedProperty(g, name); //get the value if the collection isn't null
            System.out.println(cod);
        }
    }
```